# update column values by looking up value from another table

Tags: r, lookup

So I want to be able to find the ScoreLU value based on the df table. For example the value of 1.3730682 in DSCRpd should return the ScoreLU value of 60 because it is larger than 1.35 but less than the next value of 1.65.

On the other hand for the Leverage column it needs to be in Desc order i.e. the first value of 2.01 should return the value of 60 as it is less than 2.5 but greater than the next value of 2.0.

```
[df][1]
   DSCRpd Leverage         TCB
1  1.3730682 2.010122 -1590099.11
2  1.0449597 2.680051   493370.85
3  1.0311141 4.790531    21594.63
4  1.3923007 3.279903  -499326.76
5  1.6443938 3.853003   988780.79
6  0.6265976 1.814359  1003736.73
7  2.1025253 4.412528  1245305.83
8  1.2872873 2.074424  -688305.83
9  0.5088294 2.504510  1406986.68
10 1.7794307 3.724905  1132513.33


[ScoreLU][2]
      Score DSCRpd Leverage     TCB
 1:       0   0.65      5.0       0
 2:      10   0.80      4.5  100000
 3:      20   0.95      4.0  250000
 4:      30   1.10      3.5  500000
 5:      40   1.20      3.0  850000
 6:      50   1.26      2.5 1250000
 7:      60   1.35      2.0 1700000
 8:      70   1.65      1.5 2300000
 9:      80   2.00      1.0 2900000
10:      90   2.30      0.5 3600000
```

Yes, just like the vlookup function in excel with Asc and Desc order ability. Help.

I have a function that can get me the value properly...but how do I use it on each column to fill in the value to the proper column i.e. for DSCRpd score the result should be updated to column called DSCRpdScore.

This function looks at the data frame 'df' with column number CN, and returns the appropriate value based on x.

```
myFUN = function(df, x, CN){
if (dtScoreLU[1,CN] <= median(dtScoreLU[,CN])){
    myMax = max(dtScoreLU[(dtScoreLU[,CN] <= x),CN])
    return(dtScoreLU %>% select(Score) %>% 
    filter(dtScoreLU[,CN] == myMax))
    } else {
    myMin = min(dtScoreLU[as.vector(dtScoreLU[,CN] >= x),CN])
    return(dtScoreLU %>% select(Score) %>% 
    filter(dtScoreLU[,CN] == myMin))
    } 
}
```

Comment: The usual answer to duplicating vlookup and hlookup is to use ‘match’ placed inside a call to ‘[‘ with appropriate arguments. Your question seems too convoluted for me to attempt an answer away from a full R console. If it were a bit more simplified, it might be possible but erhaps youcould do a search on Google or SO since I suspect this has been asked before.

Comment: zack, thank you for looking at my question.  I wish there was a non convoluted way (other than hard coding the table values) to accomplish this...oh well will keep trying...thanks again.

Comment: No worries. In the future, you can use a function like `dput` in order to give us the structure of your data in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, this seems like a good candidate for `data.table`'s rolling-join functionality.

> So I want to be able to find the ScoreLU value based on the df table.
>   For example the value of 1.3730682 in DSCRpd should return the ScoreLU
>   value of 60 because it is larger than 1.35 but less than the next
>   value of 1.65.

```
library(data.table)
ScoreLU[, .(DSCRpd, Score)][df, ,on = 'DSCRpd', roll = TRUE]

       DSCRpd Score Leverage         TCB
 1: 1.3730682    60 2.010122 -1590099.11
 2: 1.0449597    20 2.680051   493370.85
 3: 1.0311141    20 4.790531    21594.63
 4: 1.3923007    60 3.279903  -499326.76
 5: 1.6443938    60 3.853003   988780.79
 6: 0.6265976    NA 1.814359  1003736.73
 7: 2.1025253    80 4.412528  1245305.83
 8: 1.2872873    50 2.074424  -688305.83
 9: 0.5088294    NA 2.504510  1406986.68
10: 1.7794307    70 3.724905  1132513.33
```

> On the other hand for the Leverage column it needs to be in Desc order
>   i.e. the first value of 2.01 should return the value of 60 as it is
>   less than 2.5 but greater than the next value of 2.0.

```
ScoreLU[, .(Leverage, Score)][df, , on = 'Leverage', roll = TRUE]

    Leverage Score    DSCRpd         TCB
 1: 2.010122    60 1.3730682 -1590099.11
 2: 2.680051    50 1.0449597   493370.85
 3: 4.790531    10 1.0311141    21594.63
 4: 3.279903    40 1.3923007  -499326.76
 5: 3.853003    30 1.6443938   988780.79
 6: 1.814359    70 0.6265976  1003736.73
 7: 4.412528    20 2.1025253  1245305.83
 8: 2.074424    60 1.2872873  -688305.83
 9: 2.504510    50 0.5088294  1406986.68
10: 3.724905    30 1.7794307  1132513.33
```

You can combine them if you like:

```
ScoreLU[, .(Leverage, Score)][
  ScoreLU[, .(DSCRpd, Score)][
    df, ,on = 'DSCRpd', roll = TRUE
    ], , on = 'Leverage', roll = TRUE]

    Leverage Score    DSCRpd i.Score         TCB
 1: 2.010122    60 1.3730682      60 -1590099.11
 2: 2.680051    50 1.0449597      20   493370.85
 3: 4.790531    10 1.0311141      20    21594.63
 4: 3.279903    40 1.3923007      60  -499326.76
 5: 3.853003    30 1.6443938      60   988780.79
 6: 1.814359    70 0.6265976      NA  1003736.73
 7: 4.412528    20 2.1025253      80  1245305.83
 8: 2.074424    60 1.2872873      50  -688305.83
 9: 2.504510    50 0.5088294      NA  1406986.68
10: 3.724905    30 1.7794307      70  1132513.33
```

For the ends of both the `Score` variables, you can specify the `rollends` argument as needed. I would give `?data.table` a readthrough if you have the time as well. It's helpful in getting started, as the syntax can be a little opaque at times.

I'm fairly new to `data.table`, so anyone else with more expertise is welcome to chime in.

#### Data

```
ScoreLU <- structure(list(Score = c(0L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L),
                          DSCRpd = c(0.65, 0.8, 0.95, 1.1, 1.2, 1.26, 1.35, 1.65, 2, 2.3),
                          Leverage = c(5, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 0.5),
                          TCB = c(0L, 100000L, 250000L, 500000L, 850000L, 1250000L, 1700000L, 2300000L, 2900000L, 3600000L)),
                     .Names = c("Score", "DSCRpd", "Leverage", "TCB"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

df <- structure(list(DSCRpd = c(1.3730682, 1.0449597, 1.0311141, 1.3923007, 1.6443938, 0.6265976, 2.1025253, 1.2872873, 0.5088294, 1.7794307),
                     Leverage = c(2.010122, 2.680051, 4.790531, 3.279903, 3.853003, 1.814359, 4.412528, 2.074424, 2.50451, 3.724905),
                     TCB = c(-1590099.11, 493370.85, 21594.63, -499326.76, 988780.79, 1003736.73, 1245305.83, -688305.83, 1406986.68, 1132513.33)),
                .Names = c("DSCRpd", "Leverage", "TCB"),
                row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame" ))
```

Comment: Zack, I am having trouble running this code. I get the error "could not find function '.' "  I do have data.table library loaded.

Comment: Which line were you trying to run?

Comment: ScoreLU[, .(Leverage, Score)][df, , on = 'Leverage', roll = TRUE]

Comment: I think you need to convert `ScoreLU` and `df` to `data.table`s. For example: `ScoreLU <- as.data.table(ScoreLU)`

Comment: Zack, thank you very much...conversion to data.table worked.  The descending (Leverage does not work properly...it is one level off)  2.01 should score 50 because it is less than 2.5 but greater than 2.  You have been awesome through out this exercise of mine.  Thank you.

Comment: Do note that it looks like you specified that 2.01 should score 60 in your question. That said, you can change the `roll` argument from `TRUE` to `-Inf` for the values to roll backwards.